# Which Clause to use instead of IN Clause in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

My Question is

Which **Clause** use instead of **IN Clause** in MYSQL with PHP

Because **IN Clause** Limit 1024 character.

My Character limit exceed to 1024 character.

```
SELECT * FROM TblUser
     WHERE Status != 'Deleted' AND UserId IN (0,10,11,12,13,14,15,22,45,114,144,155,156,167,211,439,440,441,443,445,450,455,456,457,458,459,1111,1154,1156,1165,1451,1541,11111,11112,11113,11114,11115,11116,11117,11118,11119,11656,15451,16561,17671,18781,33131,33311,33411,54511,111110,111111,111112,111113,111114,111115,111116,111117,111118,111119,111120,111121,111122,111123,111124,111125,111126,111127,111128,111129,111130,111131,111132,111133,111134,111135,111136,111137,111138,111139,111140,111141,111142,111143,111144,111145,111146,111147,111148,111149,111150,111151,111152,111153,111154,111155,111156,111157,111158,111159,111160,111161,111162,111163,111164,111165,111166,111167,111168,111169,111170,111171,111172,111173,111174,111175,111176,111177,111178,111179,111180,111181,111182,111183,111184,111185,111186,111187,111188,111189,111190,111191,111192,111193,111194,111195,111196,111197,111198,111199,1111100,11112101,11112102,11112103,11112104,11112105,11112106,11112107,11112108,11112109,11112110,11112111,11112112,11112113,11112114,11112115,11112116,11112117,11112118,11112119,11112120,11112121,11112122,11112123,11112124,11112125,11112126,11112127,11112128,11112129,11112130,11112131,11112132,11112133,11112134,11112135,11112136,11112137,11112138,11112139,11112140,11112141,11112142,11112143,11112144,11112145,11112146,11112147,11112148,11112149,11112150,11112151,11112152,11112153,11112154,11112155,11112156,11112157,11112158,11112159,11112160,11112161,11112162,11112163,11112164,11112165,11112166,11112167,11112168,11112169,11112170,11112171,11112172,11112173,11112174,11112175,11112176,11112177,11112178,11112179,11112180,11112181,11112182,11112183,11112184,11112185,11112186,11112187,11112188,11112189,11112190,11112191,11112192,11112193,11112194,11112195,11112196,11112197,11112198,11112199,11112200);
```

Please help Which **Clause** use instead of **IN Clause** in MYSQL with PHP?

Comment: Create a temporary table; add those user ids to the temporary table and use a JOIN between TblUser and the temporary table.... unles that list of IDs already comes from another table, in which case you do your JOIN against that

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: How do you get your list of IDs in the first place?

Comment: @AbidHussain the limit is configurable, you should check if you can increse it.

Comment: i have no permission of increased limit on server.

Comment: Which limit are you hitting exactly? If it's `max_allowed_packet` you will need to run multiple queries (with or without a temp table).

Comment: i have use this query "show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'"  and get result max_allowed_packet=1048576

Comment: So.. what error are you getting?

Comment: no getting error but not give total number users correctly.

Comment: MySQL's IN clause is only limited by the max_packet_size. How did you determine that there is a character limit?

Comment: From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in): `The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value.` So you're not limited to 1024 characters by that

Comment: Repeat: `How do you get your list of IDs in the first place?` If they come from another table, what's wrong with doing a JOIN on that table?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are limited within an IN statement, one thing you could do is create a temporary table which stores the values.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS (SELECT userid FROM tbluser);
```

In PHP create your INSERT INTO script:

```
$str = '0,10,11,12,13,14,15,22,45,114,144,155,156,167,211,439,440,441,443,445,450,455,456,457,458,459,1111,1154,1156,1165,1451,1541,11111,11112,11113,11114,11115,11116,11117,11118,11119,11656,15451,16561,17671,18781,33131,33311,33411,54511,111110,111111,111112,111113,111114,111115,111116,111117,111118,111119,111120,111121,111122,111123,111124,111125,111126,111127,111128,111129,111130,111131,111132,111133,111134,111135,111136,111137,111138,111139,111140,111141,111142,111143,111144,111145,111146,111147,111148,111149,111150,111151,111152,111153,111154,111155,111156,111157,111158,111159,111160,111161,111162,111163,111164,111165,111166,111167,111168,111169,111170,111171,111172,111173,111174,111175,111176,111177,111178,111179,111180,111181,111182,111183,111184,111185,111186,111187,111188,111189,111190,111191,111192,111193,111194,111195,111196,111197,111198,111199,1111100,11112101,11112102,11112103,11112104,11112105,11112106,11112107,11112108,11112109,11112110,11112111,11112112,11112113,11112114,11112115,11112116,11112117,11112118,11112119,11112120,11112121,11112122,11112123,11112124,11112125,11112126,11112127,11112128,11112129,11112130,11112131,11112132,11112133,11112134,11112135,11112136,11112137,11112138,11112139,11112140,11112141,11112142,11112143,11112144,11112145,11112146,11112147,11112148,11112149,11112150,11112151,11112152,11112153,11112154,11112155,11112156,11112157,11112158,11112159,11112160,11112161,11112162,11112163,11112164,11112165,11112166,11112167,11112168,11112169,11112170,11112171,11112172,11112173,11112174,11112175,11112176,11112177,11112178,11112179,11112180,11112181,11112182,11112183,11112184,11112185,11112186,11112187,11112188,11112189,11112190,11112191,11112192,11112193,11112194,11112195,11112196,11112197,11112198,11112199,11112200';

$ids = explode(',', $str);
foreach ($ids as $value){
    echo 'INSERT INTO temp VALUES(' . $value . '); </br>';

}
```

But change the echo for the mysqli query.

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM tbluser u
where status !='Deleted'
And exists(select * from temp u1 where u1.userid = u.userid)
```

Or you can do an `inner join temp u1 on u1.userid = u.userid`

Comment: It is a solution that does nothing. You are selecting everything from `tbluser` to a temp table and then doing a 1:1 join between them. Removing the `JOIN` (or `exists`) and the temp table will produce the exact same result.

Comment: You need to populate the temp table with the values that OP has in his IN clause, not with the values from TblUser; what they haven't yet told us is where those ID values come from

Comment: these ids values come form another table.

Comment: If they come from another table, what is the SQL that you're using to read them from that other table?

Comment: You're absolutely right, the top create table will not work as you're just populating it with the exact same values. 

In PHP, split on the commas, which stores them into an array. Do a for each loop and concatenate:
Foreach x in splitarray
INSERT INTO temp `UserID` values (x);

This will insert into the table the values you want. Then the above query will work if the values in the temp table are the values you want to look at.

Answer (score 2):

Is the list of values that are used in the IN statement always the same, or is that list the result of some other query? If the latter is the case, you could use that query as a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tbluser 
WHERE status != 'Deleted' 
AND userid IN 
    ( SELECT userid FROM sometable WHERE ... )
```

Comment: A JOIN would probably be more efficient

Comment: how to get comma separated value form you sub query?

Comment: @AbidHussain: You do not need a comma separated value from the subquery. The IN statement will include every value that is the result of the subquery.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Perhaps, but without knowing what that other query looks like, the subquery solution is easiest to explain.

Answer (score 1):

**@Abid** as you mentioned your question in this case **@Guss** is right.

What i am thinking if values mentioned **IN** clause comes from **GROUP_CONCAT** then might be possible duplicate values exist with comma seperated. So to remove duplicacy we can use **DISTINCT**.

For example :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(UserId) FROM sometable
```

Above query can give duplicate values.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT UserId) FROM sometable

SELECT t1.UserRoleId, t1.EntityId, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT t1.PermissionId ) AS Permissions
FROM userpermission t1, bill_companies t2
WHERE t1.Status =  'Active'
AND t2.status =  'Active'
AND UserGroupId
IN ( 84, 85, 86 ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Above query gives you userid's without duplicacy. This can also reduce the size of comma seperated ids.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create groups using php if there are Ids which follow by increment e. g. 1,2,3 and replace them by a OR (id >= 1 AND id <= 3)

Alternative approach:

Search Max and Min ID in your List and query using an interval (greater than and less than) and use php to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid using IN then you could use FIND_IN_SET():-

```
SELECT * FROM TblUser
WHERE Status != 'Deleted' AND FIND_IN_SET(UserId, '0,10,11,12,13,14,15,22,45,114,144,155,156,167,211,439,440,441,443,445,450,455,456,457,458,459,1111,1154,1156,1165,1451,1541,11111,11112,11113,11114,11115,11116,11117,11118,11119,11656,15451,16561,17671,18781,33131,33311,33411,54511,111110,111111,111112,111113,111114,111115,111116,111117,111118,111119,111120,111121,111122,111123,111124,111125,111126,111127,111128,111129,111130,111131,111132,111133,111134,111135,111136,111137,111138,111139,111140,111141,111142,111143,111144,111145,111146,111147,111148,111149,111150,111151,111152,111153,111154,111155,111156,111157,111158,111159,111160,111161,111162,111163,111164,111165,111166,111167,111168,111169,111170,111171,111172,111173,111174,111175,111176,111177,111178,111179,111180,111181,111182,111183,111184,111185,111186,111187,111188,111189,111190,111191,111192,111193,111194,111195,111196,111197,111198,111199,1111100,11112101,11112102,11112103,11112104,11112105,11112106,11112107,11112108,11112109,11112110,11112111,11112112,11112113,11112114,11112115,11112116,11112117,11112118,11112119,11112120,11112121,11112122,11112123,11112124,11112125,11112126,11112127,11112128,11112129,11112130,11112131,11112132,11112133,11112134,11112135,11112136,11112137,11112138,11112139,11112140,11112141,11112142,11112143,11112144,11112145,11112146,11112147,11112148,11112149,11112150,11112151,11112152,11112153,11112154,11112155,11112156,11112157,11112158,11112159,11112160,11112161,11112162,11112163,11112164,11112165,11112166,11112167,11112168,11112169,11112170,11112171,11112172,11112173,11112174,11112175,11112176,11112177,11112178,11112179,11112180,11112181,11112182,11112183,11112184,11112185,11112186,11112187,11112188,11112189,11112190,11112191,11112192,11112193,11112194,11112195,11112196,11112197,11112198,11112199,11112200')
```

However the only limit for the number of entries in an IN clause is set by max_allowed_packet (as others have stated) and the same restriction would apply to this.

[max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)